# .htaccess configuration section container to apply onto a subdirectory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

My host's file structure looks like this:

```
.
./.htaccess
./index.html
./should-not-expire.png
./uploads/should-expire.png
./uploads/should-expire.jpg
```

How can I ensure that files under the `uploads` directory are all served with a far future expires header, without serving such a header for `index.html` or `should-not-expire.png`?

I've reviewed the [sections](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/sections.html) docs that discuss the `<Directory>`, `<Files>`, and `<Location>` blocks, and it seems like `Directory` and `Location` are not allowed in  `.htaccess`, and `Files` matches only the file name and not any part of the path. For instance, this directive doesn't seem to send the desired headers:

```
<FilesMatch "uploads">
    ExpiresDefault A604800
</FilesMatch>
```

It seems like one resort would be to introduce another `.htaccess` file in the `uploads` directory. That seems to work fine, but is there any way to do this with just the sole `.htaccess`?

Comment: What about something like: `<FilesMatch "\/uploads\/\.(png|jpg|gif)$">` - [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18676012/understanding-htaccess-filesmatch-code) (FilesMatch in general, **note** above isn't tested)

Comment: @Darren That doesn't work, unfortunately. It appears that it's ignoring all but the file name itself (`should-expire.png`) for the purpose of `FilesMatch`, rather than considering the entire relative path.

Comment: So you're saying you need **only** the files in `uploads` to expire/ have the rule applied to them?

Comment: Have you tried `<FilesMatch "^.*uploads/.*">`

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess file configures can be inherited to subdirectories.

1. add next option to ./.htaccess

   ```
   RewriteOptions inherit
   ```
2. make ./uploads/.htaccess
3. add options for uploads directory to ./uploads/.htaccess like this

   ```
   <FilesMatch ".*">
       ExpiresDefault A604800
   </FilesMatch>
   ```

Comment: The OP had already stated they had tried a secondary `.htaccess` file in the `/uploads` subdirectory - which worked OK - but they were looking for a solution with just a single `.htaccess` file in the root. You don't need the `<FilesMatch>` wrapper here. And the `RewriteOptions` directive is not required either, unless the OP was also including mod_rewrite directives in the `/uploads/.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on **Apache 2.2** and you want to use mod_expires to target a subdirectory then I think you need to use another `.htaccess` file in that subdirectory, as you suggest.

Alternatively, you can set an environment variable (using `SetEnvIf`) if the request maps to that subdirectory and manually set the appropriate `Cache-Control` header (using the mod_headers `Header` directive) if that environment variable is set. For example:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/uploads/ uploads_dir
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800" env=uploads_dir
```

mod_headers will override mod_expires (since it executes later in the request). So, if you have different caching requirements for different file types, you will need to repeat the `Header` directive in appropriate `<FilesMatch>` containers for the different file types as required. For example:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|png|gif)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000" env=uploads_dir
</FilesMatch>
```

---

However, if you are on **Apache 2.4** then you can simply use an Apache expression with an `<If>` container to examine the requested URL. For example:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/uploads/#">
    ExpiresDefault A604800
</If>
```

Whilst the `<If>` expression is evaluated early, the contents of the `<If>` section are merged late, so will override the `ExpiresDefault` defined outside of the `<If>` block, regardless of the order of directives in the file.